# Feature ranking to minimize variance within cluster

Tags: python, apache-spark, cluster-computing

I am working with Spark/Python/Scala. I have data set with following column: country (28 distinct values), Customer_type (10 distinct values), Product_Type (36 distinct values), Quantity bin (5 distinct values), I called these columns feature., plus price. example:

```
Country, Customer, Product, Qty, Price
US, High Spend, A1, Low, 2.5$
US, Mid Spend, A3, Low, 4.2$
UK, High Spend, A1, Mid, 1.8$
....
```

I can cluster my data set based on different combination of features like: (Country, Product) or (Country, Customer) or (Country, Product, Customer), etc. More feature in clustering give me less variance within each cluster which is desirable however it leads to more number of cluster which is not desirable. So it is trade off between number of cluster and variance within clusters.

I am wondering if there is a method which can rank these feature based on their effect on variance...for example Country, Product, Customer, Qty means that country has most effect on reducing the variance within clusters, next product, next customer, etc.  Also I think the correlation between features does matter for example (country, product) may give me a better variance rather than (country, customer). Is there a method to provide such a information?

Thanks,
Amir

Comment: It would be a better fit on http://stats.stackexchange.com/ Regarding Spark and categorical variables you should take a look at [ChiSqSelector](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/mllib-feature-extraction.html#chisqselector) although in practice I would probably sample sample and use standard local tools.

Comment: by local tool do you mean customized code that you would write by yourself?

Comment: Not really. I  though more standard statistical / machine learning tools (R with Caret, Scikits). When you get some idea how your data behaves then it is much easier to think how to translate this to distributed world.